# React - 2 input field dependent on each other - infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-loop

Need some help please,
I need to create simple aspect ratio calculator in React, where users can select image width or height.
if width input field changes it updates it's state, when height changes it updates height state.

with my code it goes into loop as when I enter width useEffect listen for it and updates height and so on.

also I would like to skip useEffect on initial render. Open to any suggestion on how to improve.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [customSize, setCustomSize] = useState({
    width: "",
    height: "",
    aspectRatio: 1.4
  });
  function setWidth(value) {
    setCustomSize({ ...customSize, width: value });
  }
  function setHeight(value) {
    setCustomSize({ ...customSize, height: value });
  }
  const calculateCustomSize = () => {
    setHeight(() => {
      return () => {
        Math.floor(customSize.width / customSize.aspectRatio);
      };
    });
    setWidth(() => {
      return () => {
        Math.floor(customSize.height / customSize.aspectRatio);
      };
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      calculateCustomSize;
    };
  }, [customSize.width, customSize.height]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        placeholder="Width"
        type="number"
        value={customSize.width}
        onChange={(e) => setWidth(e.target.value)}
      ></input>
      <input
        placeholder="Height"
        type="number"
        value={customSize.height}
        onChange={(e) => setHeight(e.target.value)}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't recalculate the input value based on every change as every recalculate will trigger another recalculate. Hence the endless loop. You need to separate your customSizes from the input, and manage the state separately. I simplified some of the code but this is basicalyy what you need.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  //Use for input state
  const [inputSizes, setInputSizes] = useState({
    height: 0,
    width: 0
  });

  //CustomSize state
  const [customSize, setCustomSize] = useState({
    width: "",
    height: "",
    aspectRatio: 1.4
  });

  const calculateCustomSize = () => {
    setCustomSize({
      ...customSize,
      height: Math.floor(inputSizes.width / customSize.aspectRatio),
      width: Math.floor(inputSizes.height / customSize.aspectRatio)
    });
  };

  //Update customSizes when inputSizes are updates
  useEffect(() => calculateCustomSize(), [inputSizes]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        placeholder="Width"
        type="number"
        value={inputSizes.width}
        onChange={(e) =>
          //Update the input sizes
          setInputSizes({ ...inputSizes, width: e.target.value })
        }
       ></input>
      <input
        placeholder="Height"
        type="number"
        value={inputSizes.height}
        onChange={(e) =>
          //Update the input sizes
          setInputSizes({ ...inputSizes, height: e.target.value })
        }
       ></input>
      <div>Width: {customSize.width}</div>
      <div>Height: {customSize.height} </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```